# Postgresql stop start problem /bin/sh: line 0: exec: 5433: not found

Tags: postgresql

I had to stop postgresql service for a uniq problem too many connectios issue in the test server. After stopping server, I tried to start it again with command at the below

pg_ctl -p 5433 -D /storage/pgsql/11/data/ start
/bin/sh: line 0: **exec: 5433: not found**

then I tired some various start commands
pg_ctl -o "-p 5433" -D /storage/pgsql/11/data/ start

this time:
**LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type" in file "/storage/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf" line 132
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "max_wal_size" in file "storage/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf" line 215
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "min_wal_size" in file "storage/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors**

I have two clusters on the server. First one version is 9.6,
Second cluster version is 11 which I have starting issue. (And port 5433)
Does anybody have an ideas about these kinds of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

There is a bug for postgresql. when I execute the command pg_ctl, it executes the default version command library. in this case which is 9.6.
And thats why I got the error: **/bin/sh: line 0: exec: 5433: not found**

SOLUTION : I found the path which includes version 11 correct command libraries and executed. Well done, it worked.
**/usr/pgsql-11/bin pg_ctl**  -D /storage/data/ start

Also when you install a new postgresql, sometimes OS installs default libraries. For example CENTOS which uses postgresql 9.2 version as a default library. You have to be careful when you use pg_ctl command. Find the correct path for correct version.

Comment: "*when I execute the command pg_ctl, it executes the default version command library*" - that's not a Postgres bug. The operating system is responsible for finding and executing the binary - your system is configured incorrectly. It's not a Postgres bug.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean my system is configured incorerctly?. Can you explain more specific. is it my responsibility to configure the binary path?
if its, how will I configure it as default?